# Would having the CAPM help me get a job at an Aerospace and Defense company?

Tags: career, certification, pmi-framework, capm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is PMP certification an appropriate career goal for someone about to start a career in project management?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/36/is-pmp-certification-an-appropriate-career-goal-for-someone-about-to-start-a-car)

Is a PMI certification like the CAPM (for people having experience in project management) worth getting if I'm looking for a first job at a company like Boeing, Airbus or Lockheed Martin?

Comment: Baaj, I took a stab at focusing your question. Let me know if I missed the mark.

Comment: Hi Baaj, welcome to PMSE! Usually in our community we expect  questions that could not only helping you, but the whole community (or at least someone else). In the way it stands now, I'm tempted to believe that this question falls into the 'too specific' category (and therefore offtopic for PMSE).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a project management position, I recommend to have a look at the following questions:

- [Is PMP certification an appropriate career goal for someone about to start a career in project management?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/36/468)
- [What does PMP Certification guarantee about a person?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/2601/468)

Preparing for a certification is covered in this question:

[What's the best way to prepare for PMP Certification?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/3461/468)

You can find more interesting and useful questions under the [certification](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/certification) tag.